# How to use variable in the module(Login System)

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to make a login system using Node.js but I don't know how to use the variable in the fs module(LINE 7). The response is "Cannot read property 'password' of undefined"

```js
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
  var contents = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/database/clans.json');
  var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);
  var post_password = request.body.password;
  var post_username = request.body.username;
  
  var password = jsonContent._post_username_.password; //Issue is here
//   if(post_password == ){
     
//      }else{
    
//   }
  response.send(password)
//   response.send(request.body.username);
});
```

```html
<div class="login-form">
   <h1>Clan Login</h1>
   <form action="auth" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="submit">
   </form>
      
      </div>
```

Json File:

```
{
  "rtv":{
    "username":"rtv",
    "password":"rtv2019"
  }

}
```

---

Regards, Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to access an object's property using a `string`, you can use this syntax for that:

```
jsonContent[post_username].password
```

You should probably add an extra check to see if the object contains this property before trying to access its value, something like:

```
if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(jsonContent, post_username)) {
  ....
}
```

Also, in **node** apps you can just import JSON files, here is an example:

```
var contents = require('/database/clans.json');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will apply the changes and see the result.

Comment: @Erik I've edited my answer, I missed the part of your code where you're used `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Alright, thank you for help. It now works :) Edit: Thanks for the update